# Error installing Visual Studio Express: "failed to open XML file"

Tags: visual-studio-express

I'm trying to get my feet into ASP.NET, and so, I began by trying to install Visual Studio Express from http://www.asp.net/get-started, and it gives me

```
error 25541 - failed to open XML file
```

I've been trying at this since the past two hours, and I've absolutely no idea how to fix this. Any help?

Comment: Which file is it failing to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these solutions.

Re-register msxml3.dll by running regsvr32 msxml3.dll

Re-install MSXML3 by downloading and installing the package from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=28494391-052b-42ff-9674-f752bdca9582

Comment: They are now up to MSXML6.  This link should work if you are having the same issue.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3988